# In UWP, How to set the automation iD for the custom control?

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, automation, custom-controls, xamarin.uwp

I have created a custom control in Xamarin Forms. For testing, I used the automation ID property in forms but I am unable to get the automation id in the inspect tool. If I set a dummy native control, I am able to get the automation property but if I didn't set the native control the automation id is not shown. Setting a dummy native control is not a good practice so anyone please help how to get the automation id for the custom control. I have attached my sample below:
[Sample Link](https://github.com/Eswaran17392/Test/blob/master/FormsCustomControl.zip)

The custom control code snippet is provided below:

```
class FormsCustomLayout : TemplatedView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty InputViewProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(InputView), typeof(View), typeof(FormsCustomLayout), null, BindingMode.Default, null, OnInputViewChanged);

    private static void OnInputViewChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        (bindable as FormsCustomLayout).OnInputViewChanged(oldValue, newValue);
    }

    private void OnInputViewChanged(object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var oldView = (View)oldValue;
        if (oldView != null)
        {
            if (this.contentGrid.Children.Contains(oldView))
            {
                oldView.SizeChanged -= OnInputViewSizeChanged;
                oldView.BindingContext = null;
                this.contentGrid.Children.Remove(oldView);
            }
        }

        var newView = (View)newValue;
        if (newView != null)
        {
            newView.SizeChanged += OnInputViewSizeChanged;
            newView.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;
            newView.HeightRequest = 60;
             this.contentGrid.Children.Add(newView);
        }
    }

    private void OnInputViewSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public  View InputView
    {
        get { return (View)GetValue(InputViewProperty); }
        set { SetValue(InputViewProperty, value); }
    }

    internal void UpdateText(object text)
    {
        this.Text = (string)text;
    }

    private readonly Grid contentGrid = new Grid();

    public FormsCustomLayout()
    {
        this.ControlTemplate = new ControlTemplate(typeof(StackLayout));
        ((StackLayout)Children[0]).Children.Add(this.contentGrid);
        if (InputView != null)
        {
            this.contentGrid.Children.Add(InputView);
        }
    }

    internal string Text { get; private set; }
}
```

The custom renderer code is provided below:

class FormsCustomLayoutRenderer : ViewRenderer<FormsCustomLayout, FrameworkElement>
{
private FormsCustomLayout inputLayout;

```
    internal string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    internal static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(FormsCustomLayoutRenderer), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnTextPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnTextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        (d as FormsCustomLayoutRenderer).OnTextPropertyChanged();
    }

    private void OnTextPropertyChanged()
    {
        inputLayout?.UpdateText(this.Text);
    }

    private Panel inputViewRenderer;

    private TextBox nativeTextBox;

    protected override void SetAutomationId(string id)
    {
        if (this.Control == null)
        {
            base.SetAutomationId(id);
        }
        else
        {
            this.SetAutomationPropertiesAutomationId(id);
            this.Control.SetAutomationPropertiesAutomationId(id);
        }
    }

    protected override AutomationPeer OnCreateAutomationPeer()
    {
        if (this.Control == null)
        {
            return new FormsCustomLayoutAutomationPeer(this);
        }

        return new FormsCustomLayoutAutomationPeer(this.Control);
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<FormsCustomLayout> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        var element = e.NewElement;
        if (element != null && element is FormsCustomLayout)
        {

            inputLayout = element as FormsCustomLayout;
            UpdateNativeView(inputLayout.InputView);
        }
        // setting Dummy native control.
       // SetNativeControl(new Grid());
    }

    private void UpdateNativeView(View inputView)
    {
        if (inputView == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (Platform.GetRenderer(inputView) == null)
        {
            Platform.SetRenderer(inputView, Platform.CreateRenderer(inputView));
        }

        var renderer = Platform.GetRenderer(inputView);
        inputViewRenderer = renderer as Panel;
        nativeTextBox = GetNativeTextBox(inputViewRenderer);
        if (nativeTextBox is FormsTextBox)
        {
            (nativeTextBox as FormsTextBox).BackgroundFocusBrush = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
        }

        if (nativeTextBox is TextBox)
        {
            if (nativeTextBox != null)
            {
                nativeTextBox.IsTabStop = inputLayout.IsEnabled;
                SetBinding(TextProperty, new Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.Binding { Source = nativeTextBox, Path = new PropertyPath("Text"), Mode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.BindingMode.TwoWay });
            }
        }

        Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (nativeTextBox == null)
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    private TextBox GetNativeTextBox(FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
    {
        TextBox textBox = null;
        int childCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(frameworkElement);
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(frameworkElement, i);
            if (child is TextBox)
            {
                textBox = child as TextBox;
            }
            else if (child is FrameworkElement innerElement)
            {
                textBox = GetNativeTextBox(innerElement);
            }

            if (textBox != null)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        return textBox;
    }

    public static void Init()
    {
    }
}

internal class FormsCustomLayoutAutomationPeer : FrameworkElementAutomationPeer
{
    public FormsCustomLayoutAutomationPeer(FrameworkElement owner) : base(owner)
    {
    }

    protected override AutomationControlType GetAutomationControlTypeCore()
    {
        return AutomationControlType.Custom;
    }

    protected override string GetClassNameCore()
    {
        return "FormsCustomLayout";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/set-a-unique-automation-property-for-windows-store-controls-for-testing?view=vs-2019). you could Set the property [implicitly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/set-a-unique-automation-property-for-windows-store-controls-for-testing?view=vs-2019#set-the-property-implicitly).